# Azure AD B2C SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am trying to configure SSO in my B2C tenant but unsuccessful.

Currently, my B2C tenant is set up to authenticate user access to my web applications via the use of Custom Policy.  User info and credentials are stored in local account in the tenant.  Upon authentication a JWT is returned to my web application and my web application creates a cookie to maintain the session.

Due to the need to produce SAML assertion to our business partner I am looking to configure SSO in my tenant.  I observe that after I invoke the SignIn Custom Policy and successfully log in a SSO cookie x-ms-cpim-sso:cbiab2c..... is created.  But when I open a new tab on the same browser and invoke the same SignIn Custom Policy again I am prompted to login again with my username and password again.  I expected to be brought to the returnURI since I have already been authenticated in the first tab.  And right at this moment the SSO cookie x-ms-cpim-sso:cbiab2c.... already disappear!

I have added the following to my RP XML

```xml
     <UserJourneyBehaviors>
        <SingleSignOn Scope="Tenant" KeepAliveInDays="1" />
        <SessionExpiryType>Rolling</SessionExpiryType>
        <SessionExpiryInSeconds>1800</SessionExpiryInSeconds>
        <ScriptExecution>Allow</ScriptExecution>        
     </UserJourneyBehaviors>
```

And I have added the following to the UserJourney before step 1

```xml
    <UserJourney Id="SignInSSO"  DefaultCpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer">
        <Authorization>
                <AuthorizationTechnicalProfiles>
                    <AuthorizationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="UserInfoAuthorization" />
                </AuthorizationTechnicalProfiles>
            </Authorization>
            <OrchestrationSteps>
                <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signinUsername">
```

And the technical profile "UserInfoAuthorization" is the following:

```xml
    <TechnicalProfile Id="UserInfoAuthorization">
            <DisplayName>UserInfo authorization</DisplayName>
            <Protocol Name="None" />
            <InputTokenFormat>JWT</InputTokenFormat>
            <Metadata>
            <Item Key="issuer">https://cbiab2cdev.b2clogin.com/042d9ae4-38a5-4443-9281-1234567890/v2.0/</Item>
            <Item Key="audience">[ "0bc2ac13-bx10-3e4b-976f-1234567890" ]</Item>
            <Item Key="client_assertion_type">urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer</Item>
            </Metadata>
            <CryptographicKeys>
              <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
            </CryptographicKeys>
            <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
            </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Please advise what I am missing and have done wrong.

Thanks,
Sam

I expect to not be challenged to log on again on a different tab of the browser if I have already logged on in another tab.

Comment: I have resolved the problem by removing "prompt=login" from the calling URL.

Comment: It's great to hear that you were able to resolve your issue. Could you please document your solution in an answer? It would provide clarity for those encountering similar technical challenges within the community.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem by removing "prompt=login" from the calling URL